# Knock out drum sizing for 10 times velocity reduction

Tags: velocity

How can I size a drum such that the velocity is reduced by 10 times inside the vessel.
My velocity in the pipe entering the drum is 9.77 m/s. Velocity inside the drum should be 10 times less than 9.77 m/s[image: Suction Drum representation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the size of the inlet pipe, find the area of the hole using $A=\pi r^2$. Multiple the area by 10. Since the drum is round, find the radius using $r=\sqrt {\frac {A}{\pi }}$. Multiply the radius by 2 to get the diameter.